# Ionic/Angular ion-datetime with condition

Tags: angularjs, angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following in Ionic and I'd like to let the user choose a datetime value but with one condition: If hour is equal to '21' then minutes must be '00' (not '30'), otherwise minutes value can be equal to '00' or '30'. Ideas?

```
     <ion-datetime
        hourValues="9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 #hour"
        [minuteValues]="hour != 21 ? '00,30' : '00'"
        [(ngModel)]="time"
        name="time"
        required>
      </ion-datetime>
```

Comment: share the ans if u got for the same.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible because the **"minuteValue"** is set first when u click on ion-datepicker to select date & time.
one way to achieve this is to compare your selected hour in .ts file and assign particular value based on hour to the minute like below.

In .html file.

```
 <ion-datetime
  hourValues="9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 #hour"
  minuteValues="0,30"
  [(ngModel)]="time"
  name="time"
  displayFormat="MM DD,YYYY HH:mm"
  (ionChange)="timeValue()"
  required>
</ion-datetime>
```

In .ts file:

```
    timeValue()
     {
       let hour = this.time.split('T')[1].split(':')[0];
       let minute = this.time.split('T')[1].split(':')[1];

       if(Number(hour) === 21)
       {
         minute = '00';
       }
       let date = new Date(this.timey);
       date.setHours(Number(hour));
       date.setMinutes(Number(minute));
       console.log("------------"+date);
     }
```

Comment: Sorry to say that's not what I'm looking for. I need to make the change visible to the user in real time, not when the datetime value changes. If the user is about to select hour as '21' I need the '30' value in minutes to disappear to avoid the user to select it.

Comment: Ohk, share the answer if u get for the same beacause it seems not be possible to update that.